# Запись звука наушников через ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Можно ли как то записать аудио из наушников

Если написать ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy то покажет только микрофоны и Стерео микшер (Realtek High Definition Audio)

На моих наушниках настроен баланс звука и если записывать через стерео микшер то звук получается плохого качества c разной громкостью
Есть ли способ записать аудио напрямую без использования стерео микшера как в других программах как у obs или shadowplay